# Big O of empty loops

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

If I have a loop construction like this

```
for(int i=1; i<n;i++)
   for(int j=1; j<n;j++);
```

O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(0)?

Assume that inside the loop is an if:

```
for(int i=1; i<n;i++)
   for(int j=1; j<n;j++)
      if(a==b) do();
```

and I want to know best and worst case, assuming do() is O(1).

**Worst:** O(n<sup>2</sup>) if statement always true

**Best:** O(0) if statement always false

Is that correct?

Comment: How many times do the loop counters have to be updated?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question?

Comment: What I mean is, you need to consider the cost of the loop logic itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as O(0), in our context; it'd be effectively constant-time (O(1)), *if optimized away*.

As for whether that's the case, no.  As written, it's still O(N^number of nested loops).  An optimizer might remove the code entirely, but the "worst case" is that it doesn't, and the CPU's spinning its wheels. through those loops.

Comment: So it is always O(n^2) no matter if worst or best case?

Comment: @bluewhile: As you have it, yes.  Big-O is an upper bound, and O(n^2) covers both cases.

Comment: generally big O refers to worst case - there are others "Big" Os - theta & omega

Comment: @SeanLandsman: O vs. theta vs. omega are about the type of bounds, not about best/worst-case.

Comment: Sure - but most people use big O as a means to find the worst case "cost" for a algorithm for sufficiently large numbers

Comment: @SeanLandsman: I disagree ;)  We might informally say that "quicksort is O(n log n)" or a "hashmap is O(1)" but those are both referring to average-case.  Of course, it's true that the big-O bound for the worst-case is also a (loose) big-O bound for the average/best case as well!

Comment: @bluewhile, note that in order for the loops to be optimized away entirely, the compiler/optimizer has to somehow be able to know in advance that the inner `if` statement will *always* be false. If you don't know this in advance yourself, then it's highly unlikely (read: essentially impossible) that the compiler/optimizer can know it.

Comment: @bluewhile: And, of course, if *you* know it will always be false...you'd do better to just remove the code altogether anyway.  :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ok, now thats a good point. I thought that, although not precise, big O was worst, big omega "best" and theta average.  As I'm not 100% sure now I think some re-reading of my algo books is in order :-)

Answer (score 3):

Take n = 3, for the first loop, the following happens:

```
i = 1
i < 3 => true
  j = 1
  j < 3 => true
  j++
  j < 3 => true
  j++
  j < 3 => false
i++
i < 3 => true
  j = 1
...
```

All these increments and checks still need to happen regardless of whether or not there's any other code in the loop.

So it will be best + worst case O(n<sup>2</sup>).

There is of course the possibility that the optimiser will see nothing happens in the loop and removes it completely. But saying the best-case for loop is O(1) will probably be considered wrong, even though it's technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

They are O(n^2) - but really this is only relevant if the cost of the loop itself is significant.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=1; i<n;i++)
    for(int j=1; j<n;j++);
```

O(n^2), even if you do nothing counters get updated.

So for the second question both best and worse are O(n^2)