# Time complexity of empty nested loops

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

What would be the complexity of the below code ( As the 2nd and 3rd loop do not have a body, it is confusing ):

```
for(int h =0; h<n;h+=2)

{

for (int j =1; j<=n*n; j*=3)

;

for (int k =2; k+k <=n;++k)

;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O of empty loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076722/big-o-of-empty-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be O(n^2 lg n)(pointed by RulerOfJustice) on average case.
As for the question about empty body the answer is that empty body doesn't effect complexity, you are still running those loops even tho you are not doing anything in them (even if you did i assume it would by some constant time operation which wouldn't affect average complexity).

EDIT:I did more research on time complexity and i missed some important principles of calculating it. Thanks to RulerOfJustice for pointing it out

Comment: You need to multiply each term, not add, meaning this would actually be around `n * n * log3(n) / 2 ` which of-course is `O(n^2 lg(n))`.